Error CS1660 Cannot convert anonymous method block to type 'type' because it is not a delegate type
In my Blazor .NET 8.0 application I have a list of items in a FluentDataGrid. One of the columns is a template column which contains a FluentAnchor. For the Href attribute there is a hard coded link to which I need to add a parameter from the data used in the row.
The markup/code that I have used is
<FluentAnchor Href="/admin/users/edituser/" + @(x => x.Id)  
       IconStart="@(new Icons.Regular.Size20.DocumentEdit())" 
       Style="color:blue">Edit</FluentAnchor>

Now however the FluentAnchor is not displayed. It was prior to me adding the + @(x => x.Id).
I have tried adding the parameter to the both as
Href="/admin/users/edituser/@(x => x.Id)"

and
Href="/admin/users/edituser/@x => x.Id"

but only get these errors:

